# Having problems connecting windows phone emulator to internet

Tags: connection, windows-phone-8-emulator

I succeded in connecting the emulator to internet twice. First time by deleting him from the Hyper V manager and restart it from visual studio 2013 (which only worked once). Second time by deleting him and the virtual switches. But every time the connection suddenly stops. Is there any proper way to connect the emulator and prevent the changes from disappearing?

Comment: Is your windows running native or do you use something like vmware?

Comment: It is runnig on hyper v